Cannot return closure from function
I'm having trouble writing a trait function that returns an Fn(&bool,&bool) -> bool.
One of the functions I want to code is this:
fn foo(op: &Operation) -> impl Fn(&bool,&bool) -> bool {
    let one_of_four = match (op.2.0[0], op.2.0[1]) {
        (false, false) => |&x: &bool,&y: &bool| !x && y,
        (false, true) => |&x: &bool,&y: &bool| x && !y,
        (true, false) => |&x: &bool,&y: &bool| x != y,
        (true, true) => |&x: &bool,&y: &bool| x && y
    };
    match op.2.0[2] {
        false => |x: &bool, y: &bool| one_of_four(x, y),
        true => |x: &bool, y: &bool| !one_of_four(x, y),
    } 
} 

This part works outside of a trait:
    fn foo_part_1(op: &Operation) -> impl Fn(&bool,&bool) -> bool {
        match (op.2.0[0], op.2.0[1]) {
            (false, false) => |&x: &bool,&y: &bool| !x && y,
            (false, true) => |&x: &bool,&y: &bool| x && !y,
            (true, false) => |&x: &bool,&y: &bool| x != y,
            (true, true) => |&x: &bool,&y: &bool| x && y
        }
    }

I want to make "foo" a trait function for "OpTrait" and impl OpTrait for Negation and impl OpTrait for Operation.
However, when I put this code inside a trait, impl is not allowed. (dyn is also not allowed, because it has to be Sized.) So I change the return value to a generic:
trait OpTrait { ...
    fn foo<F>(&self) -> F where F: Fn(&bool,&bool) -> bool;
}

So far it still compiles. But when I try to implement it for Negation:
impl OpTrait for Negation {...
    fn foo<F>(&self) -> F where F: Fn(&bool,&bool) -> bool {
        |&x: &bool,&y: &bool| !x
    } 
} 

I get this error:
error[E0308]: mismatched types|
251 |      fn foo<F>(&self) -> F where F: Fn(&bool,&bool) -> bool {
expected F because of return type|
                  |this type parameter
252 |         |&x: &bool,&y: &bool| !x
expected type parameter F, found closure|
note: expected type parameter F
found closure [closure@src/...]
help: every closure has a distinct type and so could not always match the caller-chosen type of parameter F

Apparently I can't return a function (Fn closure), because the type is distinct.
After failing with Fn, I turned to fn. I was able to make progress thus:
fn negate_two(&x: &bool,&y: &bool) -> bool { 
    !x 
}...
fn not_x_and_y(x: &bool, y: &bool) -> bool { !*x && *y }
fn x_and_not_y(x: &bool, y: &bool) -> bool { *x && !*y }
fn xor(x: &bool, y: &bool) -> bool { *x != *y }
fn and(x: &bool, y: &bool) -> bool { *x && *y }

And then choosing one of these to return:
impl OpTrait for Negation { ...
    fn foo(&self) -> fn(&bool,&bool) -> bool {
        negate_two
    }
}

But I still can't invert a function as I want to do with one_of_four:
fn negate_function(f: fn(&bool,&bool) -> bool) -> fn(&bool,&bool) -> bool {
    !f
}
Error:error[E0600]: cannot apply unary operator ! to type for<'a, 'b> fn(&'a bool, &'b bool) -> bool

Is there any way to return an Fn from a trait function? Or to return an fn from another fn?
Edit: I accidentally wrote that fn foo works outside a trait, when I should've written fn foo_part_1. Corrected.
Thanks to kmdreko pointing this out and the compiler's advice, I was able to get this working:
fn foo(op: &Operation) -> Box<dyn Fn(&bool,&bool) -> bool> {
    let one_of_four = match (op.2.0[0], op.2.0[1]) {
        (false, false) => |&x: &bool,&y: &bool| !x && y,
        (false, true) => |&x: &bool,&y: &bool| x && !y,
        (true, false) => |&x: &bool,&y: &bool| x != y,
        (true, true) => |&x: &bool,&y: &bool| x && y
    };
    match op.2.0[2] {
        false => Box::new(move |x: &bool, y: &bool| one_of_four(x, y)),
        true => Box::new(move |x: &bool, y: &bool| !one_of_four(x, y)),
    } 
}

Then I put it in the trait
trait OpTrait { ...
    fn foo(&self) -> Box<dyn Fn(&bool, &bool) -> bool>
}

impl OpTrait for Operation {
    fn foo(&self) -> Box<dyn Fn(&bool, &bool) -> bool> {
        let one_of_four = 
        match (self.2.0[0], self.2.0[1]) {
            (false, false) => Box::new(|x: &bool, y: &bool| !*x && *y),
            (false, true) => Box::new(|x: &bool, y: &bool| *x && !*y),
            (true, false) => Box::new(|x: &bool, y: &bool| *x != *y),
            (true, true) => Box::new(|x: &bool, y: &bool| *x && *y),
        };
        match self.2.0[2] {
            false => move |x: &bool, y: &bool| one_of_four(x,y),
            true => move |x: &bool,y: &bool| !one_of_four(x,y)
        }
    }
} 

Unfortunately, I get the following error:
error[E0308]: `match` arms have incompatible types
    |
325 | /         match (self.2.0[0], self.2.0[1]) {
326 | |             (false, false) => Box::new(|x: &bool, y: &bool| !*x && *y),
    | |                               ----------------------------------------
    | |                               |        |
    | |                               |        the expected closure
    | |                               this is found to be of type `Box<[closure@src/...1]>`
327 | |             (false, true) => Box::new(|x: &bool, y: &bool| *x && !*y),
    | |                              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ expected closure, found a different closure
328 | |             (true, false) => Box::new(|x: &bool, y: &bool| *x != *y), // aka xor
329 | |             (true, true) => Box::new(|x: &bool, y: &bool| *x && *y),
330 | |         };
    | |_________- `match` arms have incompatible types
    |
    = note: expected struct `Box<[closure@src/...]>`
               found struct `Box<[closure@src/...]>`
    = note: no two closures, even if identical, have the same type
    = help: consider boxing your closure and/or using it as a trait object

Rust playground link to check: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=15526934b939f8bfa0062fb31f193528

"this code works outside of a trait" - not from what I can tell: playground link. Though the compiler suggests a fix by returning Box<dyn Fn...> instead, which will probably work in your trait as well.

nit: Might just be the demonstration code but usually you'd pass types implementing Copy by value rather than by reference. i.e. &bool -> bool, remove the dereferences and just copy the value if needed at call site.

@cafce25 I believe owning values would limit what the function could do, becoming either an FnOnce or FnMut. I want to call it multiple times without taking ownership.

No, the parameters have no effect whatsoever on the type Fn vs FnMut vs FnOnce. The type only depends on what the closure closes over (the variables it captures and how). Even if it did affect it, bool is Copy so would not restruct your function beyond Fn as an owned capture.

Answer by OP. The problem has been resolved.
impl OpTrait for Operation {
    fn foo(&self) -> Box<dyn Fn(&bool, &bool) -> bool> {
        let one_of_four = 
        match (self.2.0[0], self.2.0[1]) {
            (false, false) => |x: &bool, y: &bool| !*x && *y,
            (false, true) => |x: &bool, y: &bool| *x && !*y,
            (true, false) => |x: &bool, y: &bool| *x != *y,
            (true, true) => |x: &bool, y: &bool| *x && *y,
        };
        match self.2.0[2] {
            false => Box::new(move |x: &bool, y: &bool| one_of_four(x,y)),
            true => Box::new(move |x: &bool,y: &bool| !one_of_four(x,y)),
        }
    }
}

https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=064903723747cb39b20c6eae9bceedd3
Match was not allowed to assign one out of different closures to the same variable, even within Box. But a function can output a trait object (dyn). Box solved the problem.

Note: I was having some trouble with calling the function, but I found this works: Box::leak(self.function())(&x,&y)

Box::leak() will leak memory, you probably don't want that.

@ChayimFriedman Do you know of a better way?

Returning a Box<dyn Fn> is certainly possible, but I don't know how much that gains over having the eager foo(&Operation, bool, bool) -> bool. Just hang onto the Operation and call foo whenever you would've called the dyn Fn. This would probably read even better as a method taking &self on Operation.
struct Operation((), (), ([bool; 2],));

// or, impl Operation { fn foo(&self, x: bool, y: bool) -> bool {...} }
fn foo(op: &Operation, x: bool, y: bool) -> bool {
    let one_of_four = match (op.2.0[0], op.2.0[1]) {
        (false, false) => !x && y,
        (false, true) => x && !y,
        (true, false) => x != y,
        (true, true) => x && y,
    };

    if op.2.0[2] {
        !one_of_four
    } else {
        one_of_four
    }
}

If you really need the closure, at least you don't need it as a dyn Fn:
// this is the closure you were originally returning from foo,
// although it does capture op
let f = |x, y| foo(op, x, y);


I thought that I needed it for the following
fn process_opt<F,T>(a: Option<T>, b: Option<T>, func: F) -> Option<T> 

where F: Fn(&T, &T) -> T {

 match (a,b) {

  (Some(x), Some(y)) => Some(func(&x,&y)),

 }

}

But on second examination, you are right lol, I can just call it
